# Rule to pronounce words ending with "age"

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a rule to pronounce words ending with "age" ?

ex : **usage** , **outage** => normal pronunciation of word "age"

ex : **sabotage** , **mirage** => seems to be french pronunciation of "age"

Comment: And then there's the page / rage / assuage pronunciation. (Usage and outage employ the schwa.)

Answer (score 2):

The normal pronunciation is that of "usage".
Nouns that are still felt as French words have the French pronunciation.
The word garage has two pronunciations in BrE, and a third in AmE (different stress).